# Right way to remove an element in std::set<Node *>

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc, stdset

I have a graph class

```
struct Graph
{
  list<Node *> vertices;
};


int main()
{
  Graph g;
  // fill out graph

  return 0;
}
```

I want to perform a Dijkstra-shortest-path-like algorithm. Step 1 would be creating a set out of all the nodes, which I accomplish by

```
set<Node *> outstanding;
for (auto itx=g.vertices.begin(); itx!=g.vertices.end(); itx++)
{
  outstanding.insert(*itx);
}
```

Step 2 would be to extract the vertex with a certain property

```
  double max_height_comp = (*(g.vertices.begin()))->max_height;
  set<Node *>::const_iterator it_max;
  while (!outstanding.empty())
  {
    for (auto its=outstanding.begin(); its!=outstanding.end(); its++)
    {
      if ((*its)->max_height >= max_height_comp)
      {
        max_height_comp = (*its)->max_height;
        it_max = its;
      }
    } 
 outstanding.erase(it_max);
```

I'm getting these runtime errors

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7fc485c02de0: pointer being freed was not allocated 
malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I fear that `erase()` is calling `free()` or `delete` on the elements of `outstanding` which are pointers. But why would it do that? I just want to delete the value of the pointer from the set, I don't want to delete the data that the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: I suspect you're erasing an iterator to the same node twice.  Can you show the code where you initialise `it_max` and `max_height_comp` between erases?

Comment: @PeterBell Thanks for the comment. I edited the post.

Comment: So let's break this down.  All your loop does is erase the maximum item in the set that is greater than or equal to `(*(g.vertices.begin()))->max_height;`?  Is that correct?  If so, this does not require a `for` loop.  The max item can be obtained using `std::max_element` and compare against `max_height`.  If so, erase that iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've shown, I think you aren't resetting `it_max` or `max_height_comp` between loop iterations. Thus on the second loop trip, everything is less than `max_height_comp` and `it_max` is never updated.

This problem can be avoided entirely by using a function from `<algorithm>`, that way the variables are kept within the correct scope by construction.

```
while (!outstanding.empty())
{
    auto it_max = std::max_element(outstanding.begin(), outstanding.end(),
        [](Node * left, Node * right)
        {
            return left->max_height < right->max_height;
        });

    Node * node_max = *it_max;
    outstanding.erase(it_max);

    // Use the node
}
```

Comment: `outstanding` is a `std::set`... There are better ways to get the max element

Comment: How about -- `it_max = std::prev(outstanding.end());`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that won't work because the set is ordered by address and not by height.  Furthermore, the set couldn't be ordered by height without losing elements that have the same height as each other.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be updating `max_height_comp` for each iteration.  After the first time thru the `while` loop, it will keep the largest value from the previous iteration, so that `it_max` will not be updated and you'll try to erase that node a second time.  You need to reset `max_height_comp` at the start of every loop, using the data contained within `outstanding` or a number smaller than any possible value you could have.

There's also the possibility that the initial value for `max_height_comp` could be larger than any in `outstanding` which would result in trying to erase a default constructed iterator.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/erase/):

> **std::set::erase**
>
> Removes from the set container either a single element or a range of elements ([first,last)).
>
> This effectively reduces the container size by the number of elements removed, which are destroyed.

It appears that your pointer is not getting updated for some reason, and when `erase()` is called, it is trying to destroy something that wasn't allocated.